# Unable to add SSRS Parameters/Filters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a ssrs report which requires a drop down filter to select  values.

The steps I have taken in report:

- Created the Dataset
- SELECT * FROM         Voluntary_CCC_Split
- Then applied where statement in dataset - where [WORK ORDER OPERATIONS TYPE] in (@WorkOrderOperationType)
- The parameters now appears but when changing to available values and selecting dataset, value field and label field i get error below when generating report:
- the report parameter has a default value or a valid value that depends on the report parameter. forward dependencies are not valid
- I only have one parameter

Comment: Does your parameter reference itself to set defaults?  Can you post the code from any expressions you're using in the defaults or available values for the parameter?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Viewname
WHERE ([WORK ORDER OPERATIONS TYPE] IN (@WorkOrderOperationType))

Comment: Kyzen this is only data inputted into the dataset. I then want to just get a drop down filter in the parameter but when i try to select something there i get a error message as above.

Comment: Does the parameter source its available values from the same dataset that you're using on the report?

Comment: Kyzen - Yes I have tried both methods with data source and another data source

Comment: If the parameter is trying to get its available values from the same dataset that your report uses, then that's your issue:  the parameter is required by the dataset that you're trying to use to populate it.  Create another dataset, that does *not* require any parameters to run, and use that dataset to populate your parameters available values.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kyzen. The second dataset can that bring the same data as the first dataset?

Comment: As long as it doesn't use the parameter.  You'll find though that it's a very common standard in SSRS to have separate datasets for your parameters (which usually need a 2 field dataset of *distinct* values), and for your data regions on the report (tables, charts, graphs, etc).

Comment: ahhh i see i got it working thanks for your help kyzen uch appreciated.

Comment: No problem - I've posted the solution as an answer to your question, for anyone else who comes looking in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter was configured to have its available values populated from a dataset that referenced the same parameter.  Instead of this circular reference, create an additional dataset that simply returns the labels and values for the data you need, and use that to populate your parameters available values.